# FB.Event.subscribe auth.login is not fired

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook javascript sdk to connect to the facebook

but the FB.Event.subscribe auth.login is not fired.

Here is the code i am using

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxx',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : 'MychannelUrl', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {console.log('event fired');
    if(response.status === 'connected') { console.log('connected');  }  
});

    }

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well instead of using auth.login use auth.statusChange

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                      //the user is logged and has granted permissions
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              //ask for permissions
        } else {
              //ask the user to login to facebook
        }
    });
```

Remember that this is only fired when a change to the user status occurs, so if you want to get the status of the user on the first run, use the `FB.getLoginStatus()` function. The response given by this function is the same from `auth.statusChange` event, `connected` and `not_authorized`